# Identifying eigenvalue and eigenfunctions of Sturm Liouville Problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Here is the problem:

$-y''=\lambda y$ with boundary conditions of $y(0)=0$ and $y(\pi)=-y'(\pi)$

My attempt is  below:

General solution is $$y(x) = a \sin(\sqrt\lambda x)+b\cos(\sqrt\lambda x).$$ Considering the boundary conditions $y(0)=0$, we get a general solution of $a\sin(\sqrt\lambda x) $ . With the second boundary condition, I got$$y'(x)=\sqrt\lambda a\cos(\sqrt\lambda x) \Rightarrow -y'(\pi)=-\sqrt\lambda a\cos(\sqrt\lambda \pi)=a\sin(\sqrt\lambda \pi)=y(\pi)$$

I am not sure if the work I have so far is correct and how to proceed from here.

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong IC initially. Edited now.

Comment: From the last line, I got eigenvalue of (2n-1)^2/4. Wondering if this correct

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the first condition to be
$$
          y(0)=0, y'(0)=1.
$$
There is no loss of generality in doing this because it amounts to a scale factor, which does not affect the second condition
$$
          y(\pi)=-y'(\pi).
$$
The added scale factor results in a unique solution
$$
         y_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
This solution remains valid for $\lambda=0$ in the limit as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, and that solution is $y_0(x)=x$, which you can directly verify to satisfy the endpoint conditions at $0$. Now the eigenvalue equation becomes
$$
         y_{\lambda}(\pi)=-y_{\lambda}'(\pi) \implies \\
         \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi).
$$
This is a transcendental equation:
$$
       \tan(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=-\sqrt{\lambda}.
$$
You can plot these two functions and see that there are infinitely many solutions where the graphs intersect. But there is no explicit expression for the solutions--the equation is transcendental.

Comment: I also have a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825373/brezis-exercise-8-30-8-how-to-find-the-eigenvalues-of-this-self-adjoint-compac) with solving an induced system of equation to find eigenfunctions. Could you please have a check on it?